# Panted & Varnished but rough to the touch

Tags: hardwood-refinishing

I have a rocking chair a Gentleman refinished for me.  He stripped it, sanded it down then painted it and put a varnish on it.  It looks really good but extremely rough to the touch.  Without messing up the entire job he did, how can I get rid of the roughness?  It's like it's got grit, but you can't really see anything.    Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would sand between coats before putting on the next coat. This is especially important after the first coat on the raw wood. I'm afraid you are going to have to sand it until its smooth with some either 220 grit sandpaper and then recoat it. If 220 is too fine, try 150.

Comment: Yep.  He didn't sand between coats;a no-no. Rookie mistake.